# How to create Firestore document with array of objects in Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

How can one create a document in Firestore using the Firebase console that is an array of objects? Such as:

```
myarray: [
  {hello: "world"}
]
```

I tried the following:

[image]

But this is the result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in the Firebase console.  You can file a bug report if you wish.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson - Filed a bug report.

Comment: Hi, I do not have the `Object` type option, how did you get Object to show up in your UI? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72707950/how-to-create-objects-inside-of-firebase-arrays-from-their-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a bug, i tried my self and got same result. But i found a workaround.

First create the collection and document first and click save.

then click `+ADD FIELD` and only add your array `myarray`

lastly click the `+` button on `myarray` and add your objects.

Basically do it one by one.

Comment: Hi, I do not have the `Object` type option, how did you get Object to show up in your UI? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72707950/how-to-create-objects-inside-of-firebase-arrays-from-their-ui

Answer (score 1):

This is formally fixed now in the Firebase console.